# Is it feasible to have a nose prosthetic that doubles as a weapon?

Tags: internal-consistency, weapons

I am thinking of something similar to the way a tactical walking cane is designed, where the handle of the cane can be pulled out to reveal a blade on the other side of the handle. What I am wondering is if there is any way a person without a nose can wear a nasal prosthetic that also doubles as a bladed weapon. I’m thinking the the nose-shaped end will be the “handle” and the blade will be inserted into the hole where the nose is supposed to be. I would assume there to be enough space inside the cavity to keep the blade from poking the back of the head. To prevent friction when sliding the blade in/out, I guess the crossguard would have to be the exact diameter of the nose hole, and the blade would fall within the center of that diameter so it never touches the edges. I’ve seen examples of people using blades for limb prosthetics, but never for facial ones. If anyone knows of ways to make this work somewhat more efficiently, please let me know.

Comment: I'm not sure I can see a problem that needs solving here? what do you want? a [blade](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TH2qgN1e0xg) or a [pistol](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=THsDpGJcpk8), it's not like examples of either small enough to fit within a normally sized prosthetic nose aren't widely known to exist, particularly as there's a small void directly behind any missing nose that could contain some of it's volume // Presumably you're not asking for it to be usable while the prosthetic is still being worn?

Comment: Do you want this nose to pass as non-prosthetic, or it is Ok for this person to be Cyrano de Bergerac or Pinocchio?

Comment: as long as he never gets punched in face...

Comment: No. Firslty he could only be 4-6 cm long with perforating the skull. Secondly the surgery required would destroy the lining of the nasal cavity and with it the persons sense of smell and possibly taste. Its also a moist environment and as foreign bodies the insertion & removal of the blade/sheath would render the area subject to chronic infections which would prove fatal if not treated quickly.

Comment: Due to the time period (medieval), the nose prosthetic would be makeshift and wouldn’t be all that realistic. It would look more wooden. The character is a peasant who gets involved in lots of skirmishes and lost his nose in a tavern fight. I’m thinking maybe the blade could be retractable or hinged like a pocket knife, but not sure…

Answer (score 6):

It doesn't seem practical:

- while for a cane the blade would have a decent length, considering the size of a head  it could host nothing more fancy than a knife. And a knife can much more easily be disguised on the body.
- something that moves into a cane does no big damage to the cane. Something that moves inside your head is going to kill you on the spot. What would happen if you got punched right in the face?
- extracting the blade would hamper the field of sight. Not the best thing to do when you are in a situation where you want to have a blade at hand.
- holding it in place might be tricky and conflicting with ensuring a rapid extraction and a decent disguise: think of sneezing or having a sudden stop and ensuring the hidden blade doesn't go away following inertia.

Comment: Blades: a knife or dagger of similar design to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TH2qgN1e0xg) wouldn't be inconceivable in a nose prosthesis. // using it while wearing it *'as'* a nose would seem silly & impractical however, is that really what the OP wants?

Comment: Well, I was thinking the diameter of the dagger/blade’s crossguard would be the exact diameter of the cavity/hole, preventing it from moving any farther once punched/pushed. Another alternative I was maybe thinking of was having the blade be retractable like a pocket knife, although I don’t know how common that was back in medieval times?

Answer (score 3):

**Feasibility Check?**

### YES!

Technologically, as well as technically, this would be relatively simple to accomplish. The results probably will be rather less spectacular than you're hoping for. Device *failure*, however, will be absolutely smashing!

**The procedure:**  Essentially, your nasal assassin will either have to lack an external nose or else undergo a rhinectomy in order to remove it. Next, he'll undergo a modified septoplasty. The nasal septum has four basic components:

[image]

You're going to want to remove the quadrangular cartilage and that perpendicular plate of the ethmoid bone. Probably should also clip off about half of the vomer.

The cartilage and bony components will be replaced by a titanium sheath which will be secured by screws. The sheath will be mounted to the nasal floor, the hard palate and to the bone surrounding the frontal sinus. You do ***not*** want to go screwing anything into the bones above the posterior nasal cavity, as even someone crazy enough to have a knife implanted into his skull doesn't want screws sticking into his brain.

The person will most likely require a turbinectomy and possibly some sinus work as well to open up the airway as much as possible. Due to the fact that he will now have a knife and sheath mounted to his nose.

**The results:**  Once the sheath is implanted and the tissues are healing as well as they can, your guy will be fitted with a standard nasal prosthesis. The handle of the knife will rest within the soft material of the external prosthesis.

So far so good!

The not so good news is that your knife will be very small, and relatively useless. Realistically, you've only got about two and a half inches, at the maximum, from the nares to the danger zone at the back. The handle / prosthesis will take up about 3/4 inch. The remaining distance for the blade will be about 1 1/2 to 1 3/4 inches in length. The blade can be rather broad, though: you get about an inch. It's shape, though, would be a kind of cool claw shape!

Bonus points will be awarded because of the yuck factor --- any enemy who faces your guy will likely be snotted on and also will be freaked out by having to fight Voldemort who just pulled a knife out of his face. Creep factor 10!

**Caveats:** Obviously, your guy must be *extremely OCD* about sheathing the knife once it's out. He must learn exactly where the sheath is, and must practice until muscle memory keeps him from stabbing himself in the eyes or the nares on either side of the sheath.

Less obviously, but of dire importance, your guy can ***never, ever get into a fight.*** Kind of sounds odd for someone who's sporting a "tactical" weapon in his face, right! But think about it. The very first time an enemy lands a punch or a kick in your guy's face, he's going to drive that titanium sheath right back into your guy's brain. I get that he's already probably not the sharpest knife in the drawer, but this kind of wound will prove deadly in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Things that MIGHT work: 1) A jack-knife- although it's still questionable how threatening that would seem, but it fixes the self-injury risk 2) something explosive like a grenade- frequently needs replacing though, so semi-practical and also very comical 3) Poison- maybe less practical for the shock effect but analogous to finger rings containing poison. 4) Something like a light saber or a phaser (Star Trek Style)

Comment: May the nares be with you!

Answer (score 0):

You could fill it with [metsubushi](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metsubushi) powder - powder designed to blind an opponent. This has a similar issue to other ideas - if the user is hit in the face, the container could break, blinding the user instead of their opponent.